# Why am I still getting the "expected identifier" error?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to programming (currently learning C and working alongside the cs50x course). I'm doing the Problem Set 1, Card. I'm supposed to make a program where you type a credit card number and it gives you the type of credit card (AMEX, VISA, etc). I need help with this error: "Error: expected identifier or '('"
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void print_credit_card_brand(long long ccn);
bool check_validity(long long credit_card_number);
int find_lenght(long long n);
bool checksum(long long ccn);

int main(void)
{
    long long credit_card_number;
    do
    {
       credit_card_number = get_long_long("Number: \n");
    }
    while (credit_card_number < 0);

    if (check_validity(credit_card_number) == true)
        print_credit_card_brand(credit_card_number);
    else
        printf ("INVALID\n");
}

bool check_validity(long long credit_card_number);
{
    int len = find_lenght(credit_card_number);
    return (len = 13 || len = 15 || len = 16) && checksum(credit_card_number);
}

int find_lenght(long long n);
{
    int len;
    for (int len = 0; n ! = 0; n/=10, len++)
    return len;
}

bool checksum(long long ccn);
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; ccn!= 0; i++; ccn/= 10)
    {
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    sum += ccn % 10;
    else
    {
    int digit = 2 * (ccn % 10);
    sum += digit / 10 + digit % 10;
    }
    return (sum % 10) == 0;
    }

}

void print_credit_card_brand(long long ccn);
{
    if ((ccn >= 34e13 && ccn < 32e13) || (ccn >= 37e13 && ccn < 38e13))
    printf ("AMEX\n");
    else if (ccn >= 51e14 && ccn < 56e14)
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    else if ((ccn >= 4e12 && ccn < 5e12) || (ccn >= 4e15 && ccn < 5e15))
    printf("VISA\n");
    else printf("INVALID\n");
}
```

Comment: What line of code does the error refer to?

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `for (int i = 0; ccn!= 0; i++; ccn/= 10)`?

Comment: You should be storing things like credit card numbers as strings, not integers.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. Take a look at the line where the error is being thrown. You're missing some sort of symbol there. Just guessing, it's probably the `! =` in your for-loop.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; ccn!= 0; i++; ccn/= 10)` is a syntax error. You want: `for (int i = 0; ccn!= 0; i++, ccn/= 10)` (i.e. the last `;` is changed to `,`)

Answer (score 1):

Remove semicolon here. :D

```
bool check_validity(long long credit_card_number);   <--------
{
    int len = find_lenght(credit_card_number);
    return (len = 13 || len = 15 || len = 16) && checksum(credit_card_number);
}
int find_lenght(long long n);   <---------
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some  typos in your code:

> Every function definition has an extra `;` at the end, remove them all.
>
> ```
> bool checksum(long long cc);
> {                          ^
> //...
> }
> ```

---

> This:
>
> ```
> return (len = 13 || len = 15 || len = 16) && checksum(credit_card_number);`
>             ^           ^           ^
> ```
>
> You probably want `==`.

---

> This:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; ccn!= 0; i++; ccn/= 10)
>                             ^
> ```
>
> You probably want:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; ccn!= 0; i++, ccn/= 10)
> ```

---

> This:
>
> ```
> for (int len = 0; n ! = 0; n/=10, len++)
>                      ^
> ```
>
> You'll want to remove that space and make it `!=`.